# How to draw div with round corners faced to the inner side of the div

Tags: html, css

Here is what i want to create using html5 and css if its possible:

[image: Red object is the shape, everything else has to be transparent, so the background will be visible behind it]

Red object is the shape, everything else has to be transparent, so the background will be visible.
I guess that its doable with css masks or maybe round corners, but i couldnt make it work.

Comment: why not use an image? I understand the challenge here, but what practical purpose does this serve that isn't 10 times easier to do with an image?

Comment: i have to draw an object which will have overflow hidden, so when the objects inside it (its children) move to the left side, they wont be visible outside the div. makes sense?

Comment: @hjuster: see the example below in my answer, Hopefully it will help a lot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the working solution for this problem using css mask. [Working example](http://www.bozioko.cz/en).
Click on Share or News on the lower left box to see it in action. Disable mask-image for #smallScaleHolder from element ispector to notice the difference.

Ok...here is the better explanation on this...
I made a mask like this... [image]

And here is the css:

```
    -webkit-mask-image: url(../img/sliders/mask.png);
    -o-mask-image: url(../img/sliders/mask.png);
    -moz-mask-image: url(../img/sliders/mask.png);
    mask-image: url(../img/sliders/mask.png);
     -webkit-mask-composite: copy; 
     overflow:hidden;
```

Now all its child elements are not visible outside of the black area.

Note: css masks are only supported in chrome , safari and ios.

Comment: Please don't just link to a live website. Post the relevant markup and CSS so that your solution has some value.

Answer (score 0):

### Edited: <sup>[*suggested transparent background solution*]</sup>

**CSS:**

```
.outer{
    width: 240px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    height:240px;
    border-right: 120px solid red;
    border-bottom: 30px solid red;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.outer:after {
    content: '';
    width: 240px;
    height:240px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -30px;
    z-index:2;
    border: 30px solid #ccc;
}
```

​
**HTML**

```
<div class="outer"></div>​
```

[**A WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/Nzjzj/embedded/result/)

Comment: This doesn't give a transparent background though, and that was asked for in the question.

Comment: @joshnh: Updated as required by OP.. :)

Comment: Ah, that still isn't a transparent background solution: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/JDa2u/

Comment: Thats not good, because the child elements are visible outside the borders of the .outer element. Have a look at my answer to see the desired effect.